# byte problems while encrypting with AES

Tags: python, encryption, byte, aes

i wrote a code using Crypto.cipher that will go over all the files in the directory/sub-directory and encrypt them using AES-ECB.
now the problem is that for some reason i get this error:

> raise ValueError("Error %d while encrypting in ECB mode" % result)
>   ValueError: Error 3 while encrypting in ECB mode

i tried converting the bytes to base64 and i still got the same problem, i thought at first that it might just be certain files that are encoded in a different way but then i took a look at the list and some of the files that gave this exception are .txt and just have some numbers in them so im not sure what the problem is.

```
with open(loc, 'rb') as file:
     data = file.read()
     Edata = Encrypt(data)
```

This is how i encrypt it:

```
def Encrypt(msg): #AES
    pad = lambda x: x + (SIZE - len(x) % SIZE) * PADDING
    print(type(msg))
    msg = pad(msg)
    cipher = AES.new(hkey,AES.MODE_ECB)
    cipherTxt = cipher.encrypt(msg)
    return cipherTxt
```

edit: 
python 3.6

```
def Decrypt(msg): #AES
    decipher = AES.new(hkey,AES.MODE_ECB)
    plain = decipher.decrypt(msg)
    index = plain.find(b".")
    original = msg[:index]
    return original
```

Comment: Can you post a running program?

Comment: A smaller example would be nice! The majority of your code isn't needed just to descript a problem with crypto. And include the modules that you import so we don't have to guess which crypto package you are using.

Comment: @tdelaney                                                                                                                   
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
import os
import base64

Comment: Thanks. There are a lot of crypto packages out there.

Comment: Hmmm, my Crypto is working differently than yours, we may be using different packages. You should be able to use bytes objects without the base64 encode. But its a block cipher, meaning you have to pad the message to the block size which I think will be 16 bytes, usually.

Comment: @tdelaney i used to pad it and it worked well from what i have seen but that was when i only encrypted txt files, now im trying every type and some of them like png or jpg require base64 and i couldnt find a proper way to deal with it because the padding takes a string but i cant decode base64 with utf-8 becasue some of the bytes cant be represented that way so this is the code without padding, if you have a way for me to make it work with padding im ready to do it i just couldnt find a way myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encrypting binary data works with my crypto package (from anaconda). You may be using a different package - mine will error if you try to encrypt a string. This may just be a straw man, but this works for me:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Hash import SHA256
import random

password = "temp"
hashObj = SHA256.new(password.encode("utf-8"))
hkey = hashObj.digest()

def Encrypt(msg, blocksize=16):
    """encrypt msg with padding to blocksize. Padding rule is to fill with
    NUL up to the final character which is the padding size as an 8-bit
    integer (retrieved as `msg[-1]`)
    """
    assert blocksize > 2 and blocksize < 256
    last = len(msg) % blocksize
    pad = blocksize - last
    random_pad = bytes(random.sample(range(255), pad-1))
    msg = msg + random_pad + bytes([pad])
    cipher = AES.new(hkey,AES.MODE_ECB)
    cipherTxt = cipher.encrypt(msg)
    return cipherTxt

def Decrypt(msg): #AES
    decipher = AES.new(hkey,AES.MODE_ECB)
    print('msg size', len(msg))
    plain = decipher.decrypt(msg)
    print('plain', plain)
    original = plain[:-plain[-1]]
    return original


# test binary data
sample = bytes(range(41))
print('sample', sample)
encrypted = Encrypt(sample, 16)
print('encrypted', encrypted)
print(len(sample), len(encrypted))
decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted)
print('decrypted', decrypted)
print('matched', decrypted == sample)

# test blocksize boundary
sample = bytes(range(48))
decrypted = Decrypt(Encrypt(sample))
print('on blocksize', sample==decrypted)
```

Comment: just one more question, how do i remove the padding? i know how to do it with str i just use the find function but since i cant convert it to a string how do i do it when its in bytes form?

Comment: Disclaimer: There are multiple ways to do padding, I picked a popular one, but its not the only way. Once a message has been decrypted you just do `msg = msg[:-msg[-1]]`. That is, you read the last byte and trim that many characters from the end of the string.

Comment: @Praxis6 - I guess it is better if it works both ways! A magic character doesn't work for binary data because you'll never know if its real data or not. It can work with asciii text and using something like 0x80, but no go here. That's why I put the byte count in the last character. You know where it is. I just realized one bug.... there always needs to be a pad in case the message happened to just fit in blocksize. I;ll fix that.

Comment: You got me thinking, the fact you could search for "." means that black hat actors have a hint on the encryption.

Comment: whenever i decrypt the message it ends up having a couple of "." at the end and i cant seem to get rid of it, i know its a dumb problem but still. i tried checking if the last byte is . and if so to remove it but for some reason it just doesnt recognize the . and im not sure what to do about it

Comment: \xe0z\xdf................' these are the last two bytes and as you can see i got a few "." that shouldnt be there

Comment: I updated the example to do a random pad - known pad characters is a rookie mistake. Do you have some sample data you can post that I can try?

Comment: 167265097-
3445827587-
576366685584830939-
576366681971738256-
5-
461093345577390605-
these are my RSA keys you can try them, its not important so dont worry about posting it

Comment: but if the pads are random than how can you know what they are in order to remove them?

Comment: Can you post that as a bytes array so I know I get them right?

Comment: Notice that I've put the size of the pad as the final character. So, you read `msg[-1]` and that's the number of bytes to trim. You can do that with python slicing by making that a negative number to trim off of the end. `msg = msg[:-msg[-1]]`. That's the magic.

Comment: they are exactly the way i wrote them just remove the "-"(6 different numbers), i dont have them in bytes array

Comment: I'm not sure what to do with them. Do you want to encrypt `b'167265097 3445827587 576366685584830939 576366681971738256 5 461093345577390605'`?

Comment: Thanks, your new version works perfectly :D I appreciate all the help you gave me

Comment: i think we just misunderstood each other, im not sure what you wanted when you asked for an example to check it on so i just gave you something to encrypt and decrypt, i probably didnt understand what you wanted to do

Comment: @Praxis6 - you already did with the checkbox... we were just tweaking the solution and working through final issues. I think we got it worked out.